# Binding a string property to a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have a usercontrol that looks like this in code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Spectrum : UserControl
    {
        public string AntennaName { get; set; }

        public Spectrum()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and the xaml ( not in whole but the important parts ):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.Spectrum"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="350" 
             Background="#253121" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel
        <TextBlock Margin="10,3,0,0" Foreground="White" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" TextAlignment="Left"
                   Text="{Binding AntennaName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

as you can see im trying to bind the AntennaName property to the TextBlock.Text property but without much luck.
can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: the TextBlock.Text is not changing according to the AntennaName changes

Comment: Does instance of `Spectrum` class is set to a  View's DataContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any way of notifying the binding system when the property changes.

You should create a dependency property, which will automatically use the existing notification system in WPF.
To do that, type `propdp` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to activate Visual Studio's built-in code snippet.

Alternatively, create a separate ViewModel class and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it while my usercontrol already inherits the "UserControl" class please?

Comment: a userControl is an DependencyObject so you can use the propdp shortcut

Comment: I had no idea you could use `propdp` to build a `DependencyProperty` automatically, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Exampel:

```
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
  public CoalParameterGrid( )
  {
    InitializeComponent( );
  }

  public static DependencyProperty DarkBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "DarkBackground", typeof( Brush ), typeof( MyControl) );

  public Brush DarkBackground
  {
    get
    {
      return (Brush)GetValue( DarkBackgroundProperty );
    }
    set
    {
      SetValue( DarkBackgroundProperty, value );
    }
  }
}
```